# Size of structure with bit fields

Tags: c, bit-fields

Here I have a code snippet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    struct value
    {
        int bit1 : 1;
        int bit2 : 4;
        int bit3 : 4;
    } bit;

    printf("%d",sizeof(bit));

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the output as 4 (32 bit compiler).
Can anyone explain me how? Why is it not 1+ 4 + 4 = 9?
I've never worked with bit fields before so would love some help. Thank you. :)

Comment: 1+4+4=9 is actually 1bit + 4bit + 4bit = 9bit which is not 9char (`sizeof` gives the size in `char`s, not in bits).

Comment: use unsigned char instead. Ref. #pragma pack(n) also.

Comment: every struct is a multiple of 32 bits ( unless pragma pack is used ).  All the filler bits are there, just not easily visible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you tell the C compiler this:

```
int bit1 : 1
```

It interprets it as, and allocates to it, an integer; but refers to it's first bit as `bit1`.

So if we consider your code:

```
struct value
{
    int bit1 : 1;
    int bit2 : 4;
    int bit3 : 4;
} bit;
```

What you are telling the compiler is this: Take **necessary number** of the `int`s, and refer to the chunks bit 1 as `bit1`, then refer to bits 2 - 5 as `bit2`, and then refer to bits 6 - 9 as `bit3`.

Since the complete number of bits required are 9, and an `int` is 32 bits (in your computer's architecture), memory space of only 1 `int` is required. Thus you get the size as 4 (bytes).

Instead, if you were to define the `struct` using `char`s, since `char` is 8 bits, the compiler would allocate the memory space of two `char`s for each `struct value`. And you will get 2 (bytes) as your output.

Answer (score 5):

Because C requests to pack the bits in the same unit (here one `signed int` / `unsigned int`):

> (C99, 6.7.2.1p10) "If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit"

Answer (score 0):

The processor just likes chucking around 32 bits in one go - not 9, 34 etc.

It just rounds it up to what the processor likes. (Keep the worker happy)

Comment: I think there is a bit more than that. I agree with you when you say `not 9, 34`, obvisouly the size will be a power of 2 bytes (1, 2, 4, etc.). But with the above example, using `char` instead of `int` change the size to `2` from `4` so maybe there is something depending on the type of bit fields? My understanding is that with bitfields declared as `int`, the size of the structure cannot be less than the one of a `int` (i.e. 4 bytes), but with `char` it can shrink til 1 byte.

Comment: @holt - It is the size of the bus etc. It likes and can only deal with 32 bits at a time.. So you get the lot.

Comment: If everything was aligned according to the bus size, then everything would be aligned to 4 bytes on a 32-bits architecture, which is not the case (you can aligne on 1, 2, 4, 8, etc. bytes), as my example shows (if you change `int` to `char` in the OP example, the `sizeof` returns 2, not 4).

Comment: What is the `sizeof` operator to do with alignment? It says that X can be fitted into Y bits. Does not mention that you have Z bits in the trimmings

Comment: The `sizeof` has nothing to do with alignment, but the way your answer is currently written suggest that since you're mixing the `32` bits output from the OP with `what processor likes`. I'm just pointing the fact that the `32` bits comes from the `int` declaration and not "what processor like". If it really was "what processor like", then the same structure with `char` declaration would take 4 bytes, which is not the case (only 2 bytes).

Comment: The size of a struct with bit fields is a compile time decision, made by the compiler. Your answer is wrong because it implies that it is a run time decision made by the processor.