# Why is the size of a struct with bitfields bigger than it should be?

Tags: c

Assume this struct:

```
typedef struct test {
   unsigned int a : 3;
   unsigned int b : 3;
} test;
```

doing a `sizeof(test)` outputs `4`. The above data can be saved in 6 bits (or only 1 byte) so why is gcc still reserving the size of `int`?

Comment: Any question involving bitfields usually involves an answer that ends with "don't use bitfields."

Comment: Or use `unsigned char` instead of `unsigned int`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Size of structure with bit fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725188/size-of-structure-with-bit-fields)

Comment: another link can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129961/how-is-the-size-of-a-struct-with-bit-fields-determined-measured

Comment: Re "*why is gcc still reserving the size of int?*", Because you asked to reserve bits in an `unsigned int`.

Comment: How is 1 or 4 bytes a concern for your code?